# Generic web service for CRUD operation using Java

Tags: generics, wsdl

I planned to develop generic web service for CRUD operations to twenty tables . I already had  DAO classes(using hibernate) for each tables. My aim is to develop single web service class to handle all the CRUD operations for those tables . It is possible?

i saw some examples like one generic abstract class having all CRUD operations and all other subclasses extending that abstract class and call super class methods. Here can i expose that abstract class as a web service? It's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the example that you saw is the same as creating a restful web service in netbeans

there are tutorial available at 
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

using glassfish server (as this is complete compatible with JEE6)

this will generate a wadl and to see that

after the tutorial above... right click the project and click on test restful service..as there is the link of WADl(not  wsdl..since it is restful)